# Is there a correlation between stock market returns and GDP growth in emerging markets?

Tags: stocks, rate-of-return, emerging-markets

Contrary to most people's expectations, there is a slight negative correlation between per capita GDP growth and real stock market returns. References:

- [Is There a Link between GDP Growth and Equity Returns?](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1707483) by MSCI.
- [The Enigma of Economic Growth and Stock Market Returns](https://www.northerntrust.com/united-states/insights-research/2016/the-enigma-of-economic-growth-and-stock-market-returns)
- *Triumph of the Optimists: 101 Years of Global Investment Returns* by Dimson, Marsh, Staunton.

However, the countries surveyed in the studies above are mostly developed countries. Is it different for developing countries?

I am asking this question because there are many people who invest in emerging markets in hope that high per capita GDP growth would somehow translate into high stock market returns. In addition, articles that encourage investment in emerging economies such as China and India often use the above-average GDP growth rates to justify their bullishness. Since per capita GDP growth is known to be almost irrelevant to the real stock market returns in developed economies, it would be good to know whether or not ignore emerging market investment "experts" that base their advice on per capita GDP growth rates.

Comment: I see that someone has voted to close this question as "opinion-based". How can empirical quantitative research results be "opinion-based"?

Comment: Sounds like this question can only be answered by gathering a lot of data from the developing countries and repeating the analysis described in those references...?